# Disabling Java Script in all Firefox tabs but the current one

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, javascript, cpu-usage, browser-tabs

I am running Firefox 81 under Ubuntu 20 LTS. I need (like) to have huge number of tabs open. The problem is that JavaScript in all these background tabs is still running which adds up sometimes to 40% CPU usage which in turn switches my comp into [image] farelka.

How can configure Firefox to freeze background tabs or at least disable JavaScript in the tabs except the one that is currently visible?

Or perhaps it is possible to nice them to say 19?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has [The Great Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg) extention, for firefox, you could probably use [auto tab discard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-tab-discard/)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I decided to give a try to Tab Suspender by Piotr Michalewicz. I'll report results here.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Nithin Danday above I found an add-on: I decided to go ahead for Tab Suspender by Piotr Michalewicz. Works nice, I am however lacking 2 functionalities:

- suspended tab goes black, which it would be superb if it stayed, say, grayed so the content is still readable
- when resumed instead of reloading the page, it could just use the version stored in cache

These are however just minor nuisances in otherwise excellent extension.